# How to add a question to AskUbuntu's Twitter account?

Tags: discussion

I followed the Twitter account of AskUbuntu and find interesting question through this channel. However when I try to answer questions I often come across questions which answers are quite good/interesting or which need a (better) answer. Is there a way to alert the person who maintains the Twitter about such questions so that they are twittered later on?

Comment: not right now. it's currently just a bot.

Comment: @jrg That should be an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Twitter account is a robot, on the same lines as the StackOverflow twitter. It used to be StackUbuntu but was renamed to AskUbuntu in order to keep the branding in line with the site. Simply ask a question with lots of views and it'll likely be tweeted.