# When does the AskUbuntu Twitter account automatically tweet a question?

Tags: support, promote

There are questions here about [**whether** to spread the word about the site through social media](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/280/52726), [**how** to spread that word](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/171/52726), and finally [**improving** our presense on Twitter](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/772/52726) and [**taking control** of the AskUbuntu Twitter account](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/3278/52726).

From Marco's answer and jrg's comment to [this question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/6260/52726), the AskUbuntu Twitter account is a bot.

However, none of the above questions seem to talk about *when does the Twitter account actually tweet a question*? I'm curious. What are all the conditions that the account tweets a question? After how many views? Or votes? I know that it tweets after a bounty is placed.

Example: [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/340530/52726) was tweeted; it currently has 76 views, 3 upvotes and 4 answers of which one has 9 upvotes. What triggered the tweet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documenting whatever I could find about the workings of the Twitter bot:

- Tweets a link to a question every 3 hours.
- Tweets a link to a newly bountied question.
- [Any question that is considered "hot" by the system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94593/177471). Some of the publicly noted factors are:

  - [The question score must be >=1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94593/177471).
  - [The question must not have a close vote on it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115899/177471).

---

The algorithm (possibly outdated) for determining the hotness of the question is given here:

- [What formula should be used to determine "hot" questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions)

Answer (score 7):

A bit of history here. Back in December of 2010, I was asked by [Jeff Atwood](https://askubuntu.com/users/123/jeff-atwood) to write [a Twitter bot](https://launchpad.net/stackbot) that tweeted popular questions from Stack Exchange sites. I completed this just before Christmas and the code I wrote was eventually integrated into the Stack Exchange codebase.

Now, I have no idea how much of the original code remains. However, I can point you to the relevant lines of code that determine what gets tweeted:

> http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~george-edison55/stackbot/trunk/view/head:/Main.cs#L303

In summary, there are five factors that determine how "hot" a question is:

- number of answers
- whether or not it is community wiki
- the question's score
- how many users have favorited it
- number of views