# Get notified about AU Twitter bot tweeting my questions - feature request

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, bots

I was recently reading [this](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/7314/364819) and I understand that the AU (I assume that there are either other Twitter bots on other SE sites or that this is not an *AU* Twitter bot, but rather just a general *SE* one?) Twitter bot:

> - Tweets a link to a question every 3 hours.
> - Tweets a link to a newly bountied question.
> - [Any question that is considered "hot" by the system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94593/177471). Some of the
>     publicly noted factors are:
>
>   - [The question score must be >=1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94593/177471).
>   - [The question must not have a close vote on it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115899/177471).

And looking back at the revision log for my past questions, I have found some which have something like this in them:

[image: Tweeted AU Question]

And when I see something like this, I feel quite excited, but I would really like to be notified about it when it happens. So I think that there should at least be an option in the settings to allow you to turn notifications about when one of your questions is Tweeted (with the link to the tweet of course, perhaps the link would link back to where it says it in the revision log or something).

Comment: I think there is a twitter account for each site - there is a ['advert'](https://twitter.com/AskUbuntustatus/lists/682137813085716480) for this but it doesn't get advertised as it seems to be downvoted too much too show... anyway I don't think there are any convenient RSS feeds that show this so it may be simpler to monitor the twitter thing.